# Changing Window Layout, to look like Ubuntu Black/Orange/

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making my own application in Python and Java.

I would like to change the layout/design of the application. So instead of having the standard Windows window design, I would like to have it resemble the Ubuntu design, the black and orange one.

[image]

I have no clue, if this is even possible, that why i am asking.

Comment: Are you asking about changing background colors?

Answer (score -1):

if you are using python3 tkinter and ttk you could create you own theme and change the colors to resemble something like ubuntu styles but please state what python module you are using to create the gui

for example

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

mycolour = "color code here"
mybackground = "color code here"

style = ttk.Style()

style.theme_create( "custom_theme", parent="alt", settings={
    "TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0] } },
    "TNotebook.Tab": {
        "configure": {"padding": [5, 1], "background": mycolour },
        "map":       {"background": [("selected", mybackground)],
                      "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])] } } } )


style.theme_use("custom_theme")
```